# Не получается отсортировать массив по возрастанию php

Tags: php

У меня есть массив `$arrGuest=Array( 2,1,3,4) ;` я хочу его сортировать, но ничего не получается. Цифры остаются в том же порядке:

```
$arr = array_unique($arrGuest, SORT_NUMERIC);
print_r($arr);
```

Буду рад любой помощи!

Comment: Где в array_unique написано что он что-то сортирует? Вам нужен sort.

Comment: @AlexeyTen,Спасибо ,но    $arr = sort($arrGuest);
print_r($arr); выводит 1

Comment: @Pavel может потрудитесь в документацию заглянуть, как эта функция используется? `sort()` не нужно никуда присваивать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$arrGuest= [2,1,3,4];
sort($arrGuest);
print_r($arrGuest);
```